# Select all data after selecting another option

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to create a submission on a form where I can show all results from a table as well as show individual results. I can achieve the page load to show all until the form is submitted, however when I then try and select all again im struggling.

On page load im simply doing:

```
<?php 
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {  
    $teamData = $_POST['teamData'];
    var_dump($teamData);
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM team WHERE dashboardId = 1 AND id = $teamData";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $teamName = $row['name'];
        }
    }
} else {
    $teamName = 'All';
    echo 'no submission yet';
}
?>
```

Setting the variable to say 'all'

```
<p>Team: <?php echo $teamName; ?></p>
```

Once an option has been selected it check the database and uses the name of and sets it. However in the dropdown list if i want to show all results again i get an error of:

> Undefined variable: teamName

which makes sense because of my form:

```
<form method="POST" action="">
  <select name="teamData">
    <option selected value="" disabled>Select your team</option>
    <option value="allTeamData">All team data</option>
    <?php teamMembers(); ?>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

I am just struggling to understand the logic of how to select all again from the drop down.

Comment: $teamName = 'All'; add this before isset condition and try it once

Comment: I'm fairly sure the form `name=` should be something else other than submit too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$teamName = 'All';  // Initialise the variable at top 

// Change the condition to this for better restriction
if ($_POST && isset($_POST['submit'])) {       
$teamData = $_POST['teamData'];

var_dump($teamData);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM team WHERE dashboardId = 1 AND id = $teamData";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

  if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
      while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
          $teamName = $row['name'];
      }
  }

}
```